# Dynamically append to object in json format based on its index?

Tags: jquery, json, sharepoint

my object is "myData.myMTgSites" and it looks like

```
[{
    "id": "18",
    "title": "Oct 6, 2015 Meeting",
},
{
    "id": "17",
    "title": "Sep 30 - Oct 2, 2015 Teleconference",
}]
```

What I'd like to end up with is...

```
[{
    "id": "18",
    "title": "Oct 6, 2015 Meeting",
    "tasks": {
        {
            "id": "id1",
            "title": "title1"
        },
        {
            "id": "id2",
            "title": "title2"
        },
        {
            "id": "id3",
            "title": "title3"
        }
    }
},
{
    "id": "17",
    "title": "Sep 30 - Oct 2, 2015 Teleconference",
    "tasks": {
        {
            "id": "id1",
            "title": "title1"
        },
        {
            "id": "id2",
            "title": "title2"
        },
        {
            "id": "id3",
            "title": "title3"
        }
    }
}]
```

I'm iterating over myData.myMTgSites via jquery $.each but can't seem to get the results of my query properly placed with its parent item

```
$.each(myData.myMTgSites, function(i, val) {
        var myId = val.id;
        var myTitle = val.title;                       
        var myMtgTasks = 
                $.ajax({ 
                     url: myURL + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
                     type: "POST",
                     dataType: "xml",
                     async: false,
                     data: qryTaskList(),       
                     complete: procTaskListQry,
                     contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
                });         
    myData.myMTgSites[i].push({myTasks:myMtgTasks}  );
    //console.log("myMtgTasks: "+ JSON.stringify(myMtgTasks));  
    });

function procTaskListQry(xData, status){ // Process the Web Service response    
    var myTasksOut ={};
    var myCount =  $(xData.responseXML).find("rs\\:data").attr("ItemCount");    
    if(myCount !=0){
        $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
            var obj = $(this);  
            var myID = obj.attr("ows_ID");
            var myTitle = obj.attr("ows_Title");
            myTasksOut += {id: myID, title: myTitle};
        });             
    }   
    return myTasksOut;
}
```

any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
TIA!

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick! A million times, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

(1) You can't create an object like this:

```
"tasks": {
    {
        "id": "id1",
        "title": "title1"
    },
    {
        "id": "id2",
        "title": "title2"
    },
    {
        "id": "id3",
        "title": "title3"
    }
}
```

But you can create an array:

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "id": "id1",
        "title": "title1"
    },
    {
        "id": "id2",
        "title": "title2"
    },
    {
        "id": "id3",
        "title": "title3"
    }
]
```

Code:

```
$.each(myData.myMTgSites, function(i, val) {
    var myId = val.id;
    var myTitle = val.title;
    $.ajax({ 
         url: myURL + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
         type: "POST",
         dataType: "xml",
         async: false,
         data: qryTaskList(),       
         success: function(xml) {
             val.tasks = createTasks(xml);
         },
         contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });         
});

function createTasks(xml) {
    var tasks= [];
    var myCount =  $(xml).find("rs\\:data").attr("ItemCount");    
    if (myCount !=0) {
        $(xml).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
            var obj = $(this);  
            var myID = obj.attr("ows_ID");
            var myTitle = obj.attr("ows_Title");
            tasks.push({ id: myID, title: myTitle });
        });             
    }   
    return tasks;
}
```

Comment: Apologies! Commented in the wrong place, I was so excited- 
 
Thank you! That did the trick! A million times, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a closure that passes `val` as an argument to your function, so you can modify it.

```
complete: function(xData, status) {
    procTaskListQry(xData, status, val);
},
...
function procTaskListQry(xData, status, val) {
    var myCount = $(xData.responseXML).find("rs\\:data").attr("ItemCount");
    if (myCount != 0) {
        var tasks = [];
        $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
            var obj = $(this);  
            var myID = obj.attr("ows_ID");
            var myTitle = obj.attr("ows_Title");
            tasks.push({id: myID, title: myTitle});
        });
        val.tasks = tasks;
    }
}
```